# Rust find in Vec without creating new iterator each time

Tags: rust

I am processing a lot of data. I am working with the cargo dumps, in hopes of creating interconnected graph of all crates. I get data from postgres dump, and try to connect it. I'm trying to connect each version of package, with latest possible version of dependency. I have to go through each dependency, find possible versions, parse version and see if the version of the package and required version of the dependency matches.

I can say that first found semver match is always the right one, since I get data ordered DESC from db. Now, to my problem. I programmed this logic, however then I found out that execution of my code is going to take a long time. Around 3 hours on my hardware, and a lot more in production. This is not acceptable. I've pinpointed my problem, being that I always create a new iterator and then proceed to consume it with using find method. Is there any way to find value inside a vec, without consuming the iterator?

I have the following structs:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, sqlx::FromRow)]
pub struct CargoCrateVersionRow {
    pub id: i32,
    pub crate_id: i32,
    pub version_num: String,
    pub created_at: sqlx::types::chrono::NaiveDateTime,
    pub updated_at: sqlx::types::chrono::NaiveDateTime,
    pub downloads: i32,
    pub features: sqlx::types::Json<HashMap<String, Vec<String>>>,
    pub yanked: bool,
    pub license: Option<String>,
    pub crate_size: Option<i32>,
    pub published_by: Option<i32>,
}

#[derive(Debug, sqlx::FromRow)]
pub struct CargoDependenciesRow {
    pub version_id: i32,
    pub crate_id: i32,
    pub req: String,
    pub optional: bool,
    pub features: Vec<String>,
    pub kind: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct CargoCrateVersionDependencyEdge {
    pub version_id_from: i32,
    pub version_id_to: i32,
    pub optional: bool,
    pub with_features: Vec<String>,
    pub kind: i32,
}
```

SQL command for retrieving `crate_dependencies`:

```
select version_id, crate_id, req, optional, features, kind 
from dependencies;
```

SQL command for retrieving `crate_versions`:

```
select 
    id, crate_id, num "version_num", created_at, updated_at, 
    downloads, features, yanked, license, crate_size, published_by 
from 
    versions
order by 
    id desc;
```

My custom logic:

```
let mut cargo_crate_dependency_edges: Vec<CargoCrateVersionDependencyEdge> = vec![];
let mut i = 0;
for dep in crate_dependencies {
    if i % 10_000 == 0 {
        println!("done 10k");
    }

    let req = skip_fail!(VersionReq::parse(dep.req.as_str()));
    
    // I do not wish to create new iter each time, as this includes millions of structs
    let possible_crate_version = crate_versions.iter().find(|s| {
        if s.crate_id != dep.crate_id {
            return false;
        }
        // Here, I'm using semver crate
        if let Ok(parsed_version) = Version::parse(&s.version_num) {
            req.matches(&parsed_version)
        } else {
            false
        }
    });

    if let Some(found_crate_version) = possible_crate_version {
        cargo_crate_dependency_edges.push(
            CargoCrateVersionDependencyEdge {
                    version_id_from: dep.version_id,
                    version_id_to: found_crate_version.id,
                    optional: dep.optional,
                    with_features: dep.features.clone(),
                    kind: dep.kind,
                }
        );
    }

    i += 1;
}
println!("{}", cargo_crate_dependency_edges.len());
```

After some time debugging, I've come to the conclusion that I need to somehow get rid of making the iterator, because that's my bottleneck. I've benchmarked the library, pushing onto the vec, basically everything.

Comment: Creating an iterator is cheap. Searching it is expensive. If your data is sorted you should consider using something like a [binary_search](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search) on `crate_versions` directly.

Comment: Hi, I tried looking into it (before posting on SO), however I was unable to get it working. Could you please link some example of people using binary search with rust, using struct?

Comment: How can I apply binary seach to my example?

Comment: You can use [`binary_search_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search_by) or [`binary_search_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search_by_key) to use the desired sorting method. It's all very well documented.

Comment: Hi, after a while I sucessfully implemented it with binary_search_by_key, thanks for you suggestion! My implementation has some problems, however I know how to fix those. Consider this question as answered, gn